# how do you stop a mail server / actionmailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I just ran a command that's sending out mass emails to everyone.

How do I force stop my action mailer?

the job was done through delayed_job and I tried rake jobs:clear and script/delayed_job stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `kill -9` on the process

Comment: on your server where your actionmailer run. On the process where your actionmailer run. Shutdown your application or all of your worker. Clear your work job

Comment: @Trip: `ps aux | grep delay` or `ps aux | grep ruby` might help.

Comment: @Swanand, if my grep returns `alorus    7975  0.0  3.0  59512 55052 ?        S    Oct07   2:37 delayed_job                  
alorus    7815  0.0  0.0   1792   508 pts/0    R+   06:34   0:00 grep --colour=auto delay`, What part do i kill?